# If $f_n$ are measurable and $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere, then $f$ is measurable (values on a topological space)

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

In Folland's Real Analysis book, it's an exercise to prove:

> Given a complete measure $\mu$, if $f_0, f_1, f_2, \ldots$ are measurable, and $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere, then $f$ is measurable.

I can prove it using other propositions from the book in the simple case that the functions take values on the reals (or complex plane): $$ f_0,f_1,f_2,\ldots,f:X\to\mathbb R\text{ or }\mathbb C$$

Also, I think that the point of the exercise is indeed to prove it just to these cases.

But I'm curious if it's possible to generalize this result for functions $$f_0,f_1,f_2,\ldots,f:X\to Y$$ where $Y$ is a generic measure space. Of course, we need some structure on $Y$ to talk about convergence, so $Y$ should be a topological space, with a measure defined on its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Or maybe we need $Y$ to be a metric space? I think it must be easy when $Y=\mathbb R^n$ or $\mathbb C^n$, using the fact that a function is measurable iff its coordinate-functions are measurable.

To be precise, my question is: is it true that Folland's proposition above holds for functions takings values on arbitrary topological spaces with Borel measures? If not, is it true for functions taking values on arbitrary *metric* spaces with Borel measures? If not, what kind of property do we need on the range space of the functions to be able to prove the quoted proposition above?

P.S.: The proof that Folland's book leads to is based on $\sup$s and $\inf$s; that's why I'm having a hard time generalizing it to arbitrary spaces.

Comment: For metric spaces this is true. For arbitrary topological spaces it is false. A counterexample is given (iirc) in a book of Doob. If noone else does, I will post the details this evening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us first show that if $f_n \to f$ **everywhere**, then $f$ is also measurable, if $Y$ is a metric space. The proof is more or less literally taken from Serge Lang's "Real and Functional Analysis". A different (shorter) proof is given in Dudley's book "Real Analysis and Probability", Theorem 4.2.2.

First, let $U \subset Y$ be open. For each $x \in f^{-1}(U)$, we have $f_n (x) \to f(x) \in U$ and thus $f_n (x) \in U$, i.e. $x \in f_n^{-1}(U)$ for all sufficiently large $n \geq n_x$. This proves

$$
f^{-1}(U) \subset \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=m}^\infty f_k^{-1}(U). \qquad (\dagger)
$$

Now, let $A \subset Y$ be closed. If

$$
x \in \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=m}^\infty f_k^{-1}(A),
$$
then for each $m$ arbitrarily large, there is some $k \geq m$ with $f_k (x) \in A$. This implies that there is some subsequence $(f_{k_\ell})$ with $f_{k_\ell} (x) \in A$ for all $\ell$. But $f_{k_\ell} (x) \to f(x)$. Since $A$ is closed, this yields $f(x) \in A$, i.e. $x \in f^{-1}(A)$. Hence,

$$
\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=m}^\infty f_k^{-1}(A) \subset f^{-1}(A). \qquad (\ddagger)
$$

Now, let $U \subset Y$ be open and define
\begin{eqnarray*}
A_n &:=& \{y \in Y \mid {\rm dist}(y, U^c) \geq 1/n\},\\
U_n &:=& \{y \in Y \mid {\rm dist}(y, U^c) > 1/n\}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Since the ${\rm dist}$ function is continuous, we see that $U_n$ is open and $A_n$ is closed with $U_n \subset A_n \subset U$ and $\bigcup_n U_n = \bigcup_n A_n = U$. Here, the equality to $U$ uses the fact that $U$ is open.

Using $(\ddagger)$, we see

$$
f^{-1}(U) = \bigcup_n f^{-1}(U) \supset \bigcup_n \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=m}^\infty f_k^{-1}(A_n) \supset \bigcup_n \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=m}^\infty f_k^{-1}(U_n).
$$

Conversely, $(\dagger)$ implies

$$
f^{-1}(U) = \bigcup_n f^{-1}(U_n) \subset \bigcup_n \bigcap_m \bigcup_{k=m}^\infty f_k^{-1}(U_n).
$$

All in all, we get equality. Since the right-hand side is a measurable set, $f^{-1}(U)$ is measurable. This shows that $f$ is measurable.

---

Now, if $X$ is a complete measure space and if $f = g$ a.e. with $g$ measurable, then $f$ is also measurable. To see this, let $N \subset X$ be of measure zero with $f = g$ on $N^c$. Now, if $U \subset Y$ is open, then

$$
f^{-1}(U) = [g^{-1}(U) \cap N^c] \cup [f^{-1}(U) \cap N],
$$

where $[g^{-1}(U) \cap N^c]$ is measurable because $g$ is and $[f^{-1}(U) \cap N]$ is measurable as a subset of a null-set, because the measure space is assumed complete.

---

Thus, if the convergence is only true almost everywhere, i.e. on $N^c$, where $N \subset X$ is of measure zero, then $g_n := f_n \cdot \chi_{N^c}$ is measurable with $g_n \to f \cdot \chi_{N^c}$ pointwise. Hence, $f \cdot \chi_{N^c}$ is measurable. But $f = f \cdot \chi_{N^c}$ on $N^c$, i.e. almost everywhere. Hence, $f$ is measurable.

---

Finally, we show that the statement is false in general if $Y$ is not a metric space. This counterexample is taken from Dudley's book, Proposition 4.2.3.

We take $Y = I^I$, where $I =[0,1]$ is the unit interval. We equip $I$ with the usual product topology and we define

$$
f_n : I \to I^I, x\mapsto (y\mapsto  \max \{0, 1- n|x-y|\}).
$$

Since $I$ is first countable, $f_n$ is continuous if we can show that $x_k \to x \in I$ implies $f_n(x_k) \to f_n(x)$. But this simply means $f_n(x_k)(y) \to f_n (x)(y)$ for all $y \in I$, which is easy to see.

Now define

$$
f : I \to I^I, x \mapsto (y \mapsto \chi_\Delta (x,y)),
$$
where $\Delta = \{(x,x) \in I\times I \mid x\in I\}$.

It is easy to see $f_n (x)(y) \to f(x)(y)$ for all $x,y\in I$. But this means $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x \in I$.

Now, let $E \subset I$ be an **arbitrary** subset (potentially nonmeasurable) and let

$$
W := \{g \in I^I \mid \exists y\in E : g(y) > 1/2 \} = \bigcup_{y \in E} {g \in I^I \mid g(y)>1/2}.
$$

Then $W \subset I^I$ is open, but $f^{-1}(W) = E$. If we take $E$ to be nonmeasurable (w.r.t. the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra), this shows that $f$ is **not** Lebesgue-measurable, although all $f_n$ are continuous and hence measurable.